# Can I use the Live SDK for development without registering and paying $50?

Tags: windows-8, onedrive

According to this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826541.aspx

In order to use the Live SDK you have get a package identity.

It then links you this page: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=227628

Which tries to get a bunch of personal information and $50.

I understand that all apps in the Windows Store (or whatever it's called this week) need to be registered but I'm just playing with some ideas and don't want to pay $50 right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, is no. I had to register and pay.

Answer (score 2):

You can Download the LiveSDK here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live/ff621310.aspx

For development you can register your app here:
https://manage.dev.live.com/Applications/Index

The needed Package Identity you can find in the Project Properties in VS

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work. After I create an application at the second link, there is no way to link my app to it. It even has message:

"If you want to register a Windows Store app, this is not the site you need. Go to the Windows Store Dashboard."

Comment: Even I tried to get a package identity for my Windows Store application, which will be using Live SDK. The link is taking me to pay and register page. Not sure how to get a package identity for development work.

Comment: Like Andrew and Algorist said, it's not possible to make use of features like Windows Live Authentication and such with the above mentioned way.